# Derivative of a homogeneous polynomial in the direction of the norm

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, partial-derivative

Let $f$ be a homogeneous polynomial in $\mathbb{R}^m$ of degree $p$. If $r=\|x\|$, is it true that
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}=pf?
$$

Comment: I believe $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = \frac{pf}{r}$

Comment: Perhaps you meant $f\in \Bbb{R}[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$ homogeneous of degree $p$.
Then $f(x)= \|x\|^p f(x/\|x\|)=F(\|x\|,x/\|x\|)$ and the derivative of $F$ (not $f$) wrt the first argument is $\frac{p}{\|x\|} f(x)$.

Comment: @reuns can you show me how do you prove that?

Comment: As stated your problem is ill-posed. $f$ is a function of the coordinates of $\Bbb R^m$, and only partial derivatives with respect to those coordinates are defined. To define $\frac {\partial f}{\partial r}$ you need to define a full coordinate system with $r$ as one of the coordinates, in order to know what is holding constant as you differentiate with respect to $r$. This is what reuns has done, resulting in the function $F$. The rest is just applying the definition of "homogeneous of degree $p$".